# column match two different xl sheets match item map with another sheet new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input sheet 1

```
A   B
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

sheet2

```
C
1
2
5
```

OUTPUT NEED IN PYTHON  LIKE

```
C   D
1   10
2   20
5   50
```

### I was try in pandas  error be like

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15608\2362740247.py in 
3
4 # Rename columns to match the desired output
----> 5 result.columns = ['Doc No', 'D']
6
7 # Print the result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **setattr**(self, name, value)
6000         try:
6001             object.**getattribute**(self, name)
-> 6002             return object.**setattr**(self, name, value)
6003         except AttributeError:
6004             pass

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.**set**()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
728         """
729         labels = ensure_index(labels)
--> 730         self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
731         self._clear_item_cache()
732

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
223     def set_axis(self, axis: AxisInt, new_labels: Index) -> None:
224         # Caller is responsible for ensuring we have an Index object.
--> 225         self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)
226         self.axes[axis] = new_labels
227

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py in _validate_set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
68
69         elif new_len != old_len:
---> 70             raise ValueError(
71                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
72                 f"values have {new_len} elements"

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 57 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: `df2['D'] = df2['A'].map(df1.set_index('A')['B'])`